# What is the difference between queryvalue() and querynode()?

Tags: java, xml

When I wrote this line:

```
this.atPutIfNotNil("qwerttty", profile.queryValue("qwertty"), profile);
```

It was throwing compile time error.
But when I changed it to `queryNode()`, it got rectified.

```
this.atPutIfNotNil("qwerttty", profile.queryNode("qwertty"), profile);
```

I want to know what is the difference between the two.

Comment: You should also say, which xml library you are using, because there is a lot of them. Also, have you looked at the javadoc?

Comment: Executes a SQL query that returns a single scalar value as the result.